# Get Component to the Script vs Instance of the Script itself

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In order to get variable(s), function(s) in another class, I have known 2 ways of doing this. First, is to use Get Component to the Script that we want to get the variable(s), function(s) into. Second, is to use Instance of the Script itself.

So I have made the following code:

**First case: Get Component to the Script itself**

```
public class Manager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private AnotherManager _anotherManager;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _anotherManager = GameObject.Find("Managers").GetComponent<AnotherManager>();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        _anotherManager.myIntVariable = 10;

        _anotherManager.MyFunction();
    }
}

public class AnotherManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public int myIntVariable;

    public void MyFunction()
    {

    }
}
```

**Second case: Use Instance of the Script itself**

```
public class Manager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private void Start()
    {
        AnotherManager.instance.myIntVariable = 10;

        AnotherManager.instance.MyFunction();
    }
}

public class AnotherManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static AnotherManager instance;

    public int myIntVariable;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public void MyFunction()
    {

    }
}
```

My question is: Is there any difference between those cases? In terms of good practice of coding for programmer or performance or it is just a matter of programmer's perspective or whatever else?

Thanks

Comment: The second case is the sledgehammer method. It will work but it can also hurt you badly (ie it will stop working with two instances of the same script). The first version is the recommended approach.

Comment: Agreed with LearnCocos2D. If the script should only ever have one instance of itself, I'd go as far to add measures that make sure more than one of it nether get created too, though that isn't necessarily related to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second example is the what is known as the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and should be used very sparingly.

I try to never use the first approach either where you find the gameobject and hope it exists.

You can expose a field for the Unity Inspector so that you can wire it up the same as you can expose any other variable

```
public AnotherManager AnotherManager;
```

Alternatively, if you hate using public all over the place like that, like me, you can also indicate to Unity that you wish to expose this variable in the inspector with the [SerializeField](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) attribute

```
[SerializeField]
private AnotherManager anotherManager;
```

With both of these methods, you can then drag an an object that has the AnotherManager component attached into the field in the inspector.

If instantiated objects need access to this, you will need to wire it up when it is instantiated.

If you need help attaching it in unity I can attach some screenshots.

Comment: Second is not fully implemented singleton. Because you can create more instance GameObject and don't destroys on scene change.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @Formic. I appreciate that, and you don't have to bother yourself to attach some screenshots to here, since I already know that and what `SerializeField` do. Thank you again

Comment: No problem @Yunnan, if that was the answer you were looking for you can mark it as the answer so future inquirers can find it easier :)